# Effective consecutive access to complete file-backed big.matrix in Rcpp?

Tags: r, rcpp, r-bigmemory

I currently trying to find a implementation that allows for consecutive function calls, where in each call access to each element of a big matrix (up to 1.5e9 entries of doubles) is needed.

I used the `bigmemory` package for handling the matrix together with `Rcpp` for the function operations.

To be a bit more explicit, see the following code.

C++ code:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double IterateBigMatrix2(SEXP pBigMat,int n_row, int n_col){
  XPtr<BigMatrix> xpMat(pBigMat);
  MatrixAccessor<double> mat(*xpMat);
  double sum = 0;
  for(int i=0;i<n_row;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<n_col;j++){
      sum += mat[j][i];
    }
  }
  return(sum);
}
```

Function call in R:

```
#Set up big.matrix
nrows <- 2e7
ncols <- 50
bkFile <- "bigmat.bk"
descFile <- "bigmatk.desc"
bigmat <- filebacked.big.matrix(nrow=nrows, ncol=ncols, type="double",
                                backingfile=bkFile, backingpath=".",
                                descriptorfile=descFile,
                                dimnames=c(NULL,NULL))
#Consecutive function calls
IterateBigMatrix2(bigmat@address,nrows,ncols)
IterateBigMatrix2(bigmat@address,nrows,ncols)
```

Unfortunately, the consecutive function call slows down extremely at some point for increasing n_rows resp. n_cols.

My question:

Is this because the access to big.matrix elements leads to deletion of the first cached elements if RAM is exceeded, but in consecutive function calls exactly these 'first' elements of the big.matrix are needed?
If 'yes', is there some better (improving performance) way of accessing the element in the loops or deletion of cached elements?

Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big.matrix objects, as standard R matrices, are stored column-wise. 
This means that a matrix is in fact a long vector (formed by columns concatenated to each other).

What this basically tells you is to always access columns by columns, and not rows by rows, in order to access data in contiguous memory ("locality of accesses").

So, **just switch your two loops and it should be OK**.

PS: you don't need to pass `n_row` and `n_col`. You can get them via `xpMat->nrow()` and `xpMat->ncol()` or `mat.nrow()` and `mat.ncol()`.

Comment: Good tip! Improved speed a bit, but unfortunately I found that the bottleneck is reading data from the hard disk. So it seems there is nothing to improve from a coding point of view.

Comment: This data is only 7GB. It should be quite fast to read, especially the second time, third time and so on if you have more than 7GB or RAM available.